# Scikit learn; cannot create plot for polynomial regression correctly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I just started to learn about polynomial regression. And I was trying to create plot for polynomial regression but the plot is wrong.

My code is like this

```
#Linear regression
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()


x = data.loc[:, ['col1']]
y = data.loc[:, ['col2']]

clf.fit(x, y)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, clf.predict(x))
plt.show()
```

This code is for linear regression model and the plot is this.

[image]

and the code for polynomial regression is here

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
poly_x = poly_reg.fit_transform(x)

clf.fit(poly_x, y)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, clf.predict(poly_x))
```

[image]

The plot is wrong like this.

I just started learning about it and I just tried to copy the way some tutorial does so my understanding for this is still bad. How can I fix this plot and also I would appreciate good resources to understand the concept.

Comment: Please sort the X data and then try

Comment: You mean sort_values by x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first sort the values in X and y according to the values in X.

```
# This is your data
x = data.loc[:, ['col1']]
y = data.loc[:, ['col2']]

# This is what you need to do.
# argsort() will return the indices of the sorting order
inds = x.values.ravel().argsort()    # Here I am assuming that x has single feature     
x = x.values.ravel()[inds].reshape(-1,1)
y = y.values[inds]

# Then continue your code.
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
poly_x = poly_reg.fit_transform(x)

clf.fit(poly_x, y)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, clf.predict(poly_x))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for making the answer more clear but
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ravel'
This error happens. x has one column.

Comment: I will change the dataframe to series object and I will try.

Comment: Now y = y[inds]
this line causes an error. ... not in index'
Maybe the problem is the index of x and y is not number

Comment: @dude I edited the answer. I used `.values` to convert the dataframe to numpy array. Please check

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ravel'
I copied your answer again but  this error happens on 'inds = x.ravel().argsort() '

Comment: @dude Yes, sorry missed that line. Corrected now added `.values` in that. Please check.

Comment: Thanks a lot, The correct plot came out now. I will figure what you did out now.

Comment: @dude The middle three lines are what you need. I took the `inds` which will sort the `x`. Then used the same on `y` so that `y` is ordered in same way `x` is. The other things like `ravel()`, `values` etc are used just to extract the numpy array from dataframe.

Comment: Sorry last questions. Does this sort mean sorting by the value of the data? Why was the plot messy without sorting?

Comment: @dude The `matplotlib` will try to join the points as supplied. So when not sorted, it will first join the point which may be at the last of the graph and then again come to next point which may be at the bottom of the graph, then next point which again may be at other side and so on.. So the plot will be hap-hazard. I have done the sorting by value of data, so that the points supplied to matplotlib when plotted on graph are in an order, so that when it joins the point, it will come clean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170275/discussion-between-dude-and-vivek-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `pipeline` to fit and predict

example:

```
poly_model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(7),
                       LinearRegression())

rng = np.random.RandomState(1)
x = 10 * rng.rand(50)
y = np.sin(x) + 0.1 * rng.randn(50)
xfit = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)

poly_model.fit(x.reshape(-1,1), y)
yfit = poly_model.predict(xfit.reshape(-1,1))

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(xfit, yfit)
```

from above example, you will able to understand and it is very important to use `.reshape(-1,1)` if you have a single column.

See if this helps you to understand...

Comment: Sorry I cannot see how your code can adapt into my code. What is the problem without reshape?

Comment: @dude The data of OP has correct shape. No need for this.

Comment: Sorry what does OP mean? Also please tell me the problem with my plot or my way?